# replace element of a list by appending escape character to each element

Tags: python, string, list, replace

how to replace '1c' to '\x1c' in python. I have a list with elements like '12','13' etc and want to replace with '\x12', '\x13' etc.

here is what i tried and failed

```
 letters=[]
 for i in range(10,128,1):
      a=(str(hex(i))).replace('0x','\x')
      letters.append(a)
      print letters
```

**I need is '31' to be replaced by '\x31' ---> '1'  not '\x31' 0r \x31**

Comment: slowly I understand your problem. You don't want a hex representation as strings but the character representation of hex-numbers: `letters = [chr(i) for i in range(10,128)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the built-in function [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to return the correct ascii code (which is the string you are after):

```
>>> [chr(i) for i in range(10,20,1)]
['\n', '\x0b', '\x0c', '\r', '\x0e', '\x0f', '\x10', '\x11', '\x12', '\x13']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, you just need to escape the `\` with a `\`.

```
letters=[]
for i in range(10,128,1):
    a=(str(hex(i))).replace('0x','\\x')   #you have to escape the \
    letters.append(a)
    print letters
```

### DEMO

Comment: brother it gives me '\\x31' as element where i need is '\x31' --> '1'

Comment: @ceasif, Yes, but when you print a specific element you __will__ get `\x31`

Comment: This is only the representation of a string: as you can see `len('\\')  == 1` is only one character

Comment: @sshashank124 Thank you brother your answer were really help ful to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do your task is using string formatting, then you don't have to replace anything, and the code looks clearer:

```
letters = ['\\x%x' % i for i in range(10, 128)]
print letters
```

Comment: please have a look at this which is my problem @Denial